# Does there exist a neighborhood around a real number on the real line whose complement is finite?

Tags: general-topology

I'm reading Armstrong's Basic Topology. In Chapter 1 - Abstract Spaces he is giving an example of two topological spaces being not homeomorphic to each other. One topological space is "the set of real numbers who are in the neighborhood of a particular real number if the neighborhood contains that number and if in addition its complement is finite. " Then he claims that this topological space is not homeomorphic to the real line.

> [image]

First of all, I don't see whether there exists a topological space like this or not? Secondly, I'm not sure how to show that they are not homeomorphic. Beginning Topologer thank anyone who could give some insights!

Comment: As for existence: The topological space being defined is given as the space where the closed sets are the finite sets and the whole space, or equivalently, the open sets are the co-finite sets and the empty set. This is a topology:

 - The empty set is finite, hence closed, and the whole space has finite complement.
 - If you intersect arbitrarily many finite sets, the result is still finite. Equivalently, taking the union of arbitrarily many co-finite sets gives you a co-finite set.
 - The union of two finite sets is finite, and hence, the intersection of two co-finite sets is co-finite.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I understand that the book describes the neighborhoods of the *new* topological space using the neighborhoods in the *usual topology* of $\Bbb R$.
A such neighborhood os $0$ is for example $(-\infty,-1)\cup(-1,1)\cup(1,+\infty)$.

The new topological isn't homeomorphic to $\Bbb R$ with the usual topology because isn't Hausdorff.

Comment: I'm not the OP, but just interested: where can I see a proof that this topological space is not Hausdorff? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks! Ah I was being stupid. This might be a naive question: but what does it mean to be Hausdorff?

Comment: @ShiyueLi, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_space.

Comment: @AhmedHussein, All the neighborhoods are cofinite, so any two neighborhoods of different points have nonempty intersection.